# preg_match to capture string part after a special character

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I have a text files with strings and for each string I need to divide and capture each part of it.

The string is like:

```
Joao.Martins.G2R71.Pedro.Feliz.sno
```

Being: NAME 1st player (only first or first+surname) G = game (can be 2 or 02 or other number less than 99) ; R = result (in this example home team wis 7x1) and NAME 2nd player ... last 3 chars are the game type (this example snooker)

But the string can also be:

```
Joao Martins |2x71| Pedro Feliz.poo
```

I'm no Regex expert (sadly) and already searched lots of questions here without finding a solution or for that matter even getting help just by reading the answers to other questions (mainly because I never seem to understand this)

I already have this:

```
preg_match("/\[(|^|]+)\]/",$string,$result);
echo $result[1] . "<br />";
```

But this only gives me the all thingy between the | | part without even separating them and ignores everything else

Can you guys help me with a solution for both cases? I'm as usual completely lost here!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `explode` way:

You don't have to use complex regexp, you may use simple [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$parts = explode( '.', $string);
```

Parts now how either 2 parts or 6, so you can do:

```
if( count( $parts) == 6)){
   list( $fistName1, $surName1, $string, $fistName2, $surName2, $gameType) = $parts;
} elseif( count( $parts) == 2) {
   $gameType = $parts[1];
   list( $fistName1, $surName1, $string, $fistName2, $surName2) = explode( $parts[0]);
} else {
   echo "Cannot parse";
}
```

And now parsing `$gameType` :)

```
if( preg_match( '~^\|(\d+)x(\d+)\|$~', $gameType, $parts)){
   $first = $parts[1];
   $second = $parts[2];
} elseif( preg_match( '~^G(\d+)R(\d+)$~', $gameType, $parts)){
   $first = $parts[1];
   $second = $parts[2];
} else {
   echo "Cannot parse!";
}
```

#### `preg_match` way:

<sub>The second regexp is intentionally different, so you can see how to write regexp that will "eat" whole name doesn't matter whether it has 2,3 or 5 parts and you will get used to `*?` (greedy killer).</sub>

```
$match = array();
if( preg_match( '~^(\w+)\.(\w+)\.G(\d+)R(\d+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)$~', $text, $match)){
  // First way
} elseif (preg_match( '~^([^\|]+)\|(\d+)x(\d+)\|(.*?)\.(\w+)$~', $text, $match)){
  // Second way
} else {
  // Failed to parse
}
```

#### Edit (more than 2 names)

And if player may have more than 2 names (like `Armin Van Buuren`) you should go with regexp like this:

`~^([\w.]+)\.G(\d+)R(\d+)\.([\w.]+)\.(\w+)$~`

This will match names in `Albert.Einstein`, `Armin.Van.Buuren` (regexp relies on that name won't contain `\d` (decimal number) so names like `Gerold The 3rd` won't match).

You should be fine with using just: `~^([\w\d.]+)\.G(\d+)R(\d+)\.([\w\d.]+)\.(\w+)$~` which would also match `Gerold The 3rd` and any other name (`\.G(\d+)R(\d+)\.` is quite strict and you would have to make up really crazy name like `G3R01` (like "3l1t33 kid Gerold") to parse it wrong.

Oh and one more thing, don't forget to [`$name = strtr( $name, '.', ' ')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) :)

#### RegExp explained

- `~~` - [regexp delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php); starts end finishes regexp; `~regexp~`, it can be practically anything `/regexp/`, `(regexp)`
- `^` and `$` - [meta characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php);`^` start of string/line, `$` end of string/line
- `\w` is [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) for any word character, the same as `[a-zA-Z]`
- `([\w.]+)` - captures [subpatern/match group](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) what contains `[a-zA-Z.]` at least once. `+` is called [quantifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php)
- `+?` - `?` (after other quantifier) is called greedy killer and it means *take as little as possible*, normally would `(\w+)a` would match (on string `ababa`) `abab`, `(\w+?)a` would match `ab` and `(\w*?)a` would match empty string :)

Comment: OK! I'm now trying to implement your preg_match suggested way ... and it works flawlessly for the 2nd type of string but for the first type it doesn't work ... is it cause the players might sometimes have 2 surnames instead of just 1? If the middle thinghy is |GxRR| works perfect no matter what! I wish I could write these RegExs as you guys!!

Comment: @AfonsoGomes here you go, is it fine now?

Comment: ah ah! working perfectly now!!! You saved me! :) Now I just really wanted to take this opportunity and try to understand the expression... what doed the ~^ and $^ do? Are they begining and end 'operators'? And what exactly does the ([\w.]+) part and how it's different for the end part of the expression? Anyway ... thanks so much for your time, already voted up for the trouble and best answer for working :)

Comment: Saw another problem now :( What about if the name of the player has a - (hifen) like in Chelsea's Manager name's André Villas-Boas ?  Doesn't seem to be working for that case.

Comment: @AfonsoGomes I've edited my answer (hope they won't lynch me for it's length) :) Those links are great place to learn... If this is answer to your question hit the tick mark and mark it as a question answer'; add hyphen to group -> `[\w.-]` (be carefull to add it on last place, it has special meaning)

Comment: No worries ... I was already doing to mark yours as the chosen answer. All working perfectly now and thanks for all the tips regarding RegEx. Feel like a gave another little step forward on this, but I'm pretty sure more questions will arise in the future! I''ll look into your links tho! Thanks! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 4):

I think this will do it for you.

```
    /^(\w+)(?:\.| )(\w+)(?:\.| \|)G?(\d+)[x|R](\d+)(?:\.|\| )(\w+)(?:\.| )(\w+)(?:\.| )(\w+)$/
```

- $1 will be p1 first name
- $2 will be p1 last name
- $3 will be game number
- $4 will be results
- $5 will be p2 first name
- $6 will be p2 last name
- $7 will be game type

If the $n things don't make sense then just think of them as the elements of the $results array. The pattern might be simplified some but I don't have enough time to figure that out.

Comment: I tested this expression at http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html and nothing happened :| Any problem with the expression? I don't know enough to even dare a troubleshoot!

Comment: @AfonsoGomes Fixed the regex don't know what happened while pasting it. Also that regex tester doenst accept the leading and trailing /'s in the pattern so remove those to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
//to get the string without the game type
$yourstring = substr($yourstring ,0 ,strlen($yourstring)-4);

//separating strings with "." as delimiter
$results = explode(".",$yourstring);

//checking whether "." was the delimiter 
if(!strcmp($results[0],$yourstring)) {
  //if "." was not the delimiter, then split the string with " " 
  //as the delimiter.
  $results = explode(" ",$yourstring);
  }

//storing them in separate variables. and removing "|" if exists.
if( count( $results) == 5){
  $results[2] = trim($results[2],"|");
  list( $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5) = $results;
  }
elseif( count( $results) == 4){
  $results[1] = trim($results[1],"|");  
  $results[2] = trim($results[2],"|");  
  list( $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) = $results;
  }
else {
  $results[1] = trim($results[1],"|");  
  list( $var1, $var2, $var3) = $results;
  }
```

All your string parts will be separated and stored in `$results`.
To get them to separate variable, you can use `list` function.

Comment: @ThinkingMoney: already voted your answer up for you having taken the time to help. I'll be testing it even today so see if it also workds to me and to suck up some more experience but Vyktor already game me a working solution using regex (that I also wanted to try and learn)